# Post Scheduling in Ruby Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web, blogs

I'm working on post scheduling model by using gem "whenever" with status: published_at, schedule and drafts. But the problem is at given time post is not changing it's status from Schedule to Published_at.

```
#schedule.rb
     every 1.minute do
      rake 'scheduler'
    end
#example.rake
task scheduler: :environment do
  time = Time.zone.now
  posts = Post.scheduled.where(published_at: (time))
  posts.update_all(status: "Published")

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task scheduler: :environment do
  Post.scheduled.publish_now!
end
```

in your model post.rb add this line:

```
def self.publish_now!
  where(published_at: Time.now).update_all(status: "Published")
end
```

I think it's too risk to search by Time.now because it will get exact time in second, but your scheduler is every 1.minutes, so you will have possibility to miss Post because of gaps 60 seconds. So that better you query like this:

```
def publish_now!
  where("status != ? AND published_at <= now()", "Published").update_all(status: "Published")
end
```

Comment: if i change the schedule time from 1.minute to One day does it matter?

Comment: it does matter, depend on your query, if you expect `published_at == Time.now` and when Time.now is executed, example 3:14:21 or 3 am 14 minutes 21 second, so it will only find Post with published_at on that value only. That's why I set `published_at <= now()` with status is not "Published" that means find all drafts that published at is lower or equal than time now.